# How can I fix a multiple build commands for output file error?

Tags: ios, xcode

It's not a fatal one, it's just irritating me. My error message is here:

```
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/benjaminkelsey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_Name-cssewxhpqzfzqsbdkukoihlpvbqc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App Name.app/.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspect your app target's Build Phases to see what's gone wrong. Perhaps a file is listed multiple times. Also, the name looks as if you've made some mistake; the file has no name apart from its extension.

Comment: The problem is that my app has about 8,000 images... I don't know how to check each and every single one for a duplicate.

Comment: That _is_ a problem, and is likely how you got yourself into this situation. Are all those images just sitting there at the top level of the app bundle? That's not a good architecture... Sounds like some reorganization is needed here.

Comment: No, they are in folders. But when I go to Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources, they are all sitting there together with no folders.

Comment: They are not in folders, then. They are in _groups_, but groups are not folders - they are not anything real. If you want them to be in folders in the app bundle, you should make these groups _folder references_ — but then you will have to give the folder name when you fetch an image. As I said, this will take some reorganization, including some modification of your code; but I think that would be a good thing in the long run. 8000 images at the top level of an app bundle is just wrong.